# Changing slider format using CartoDB?

Tags: carto, torque, visualisation

I'm new working with cartoDB and I'm trying to show the hour and the date in a torque slider but doesn't work properly and show mm/dd/yyyy instead of mm-dd hh:mm.

Using:

"http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/cartodb.js" script 
"http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/themes/css/cartodb.css" stylesheet

I'm using the following code:

```
function main() {
   cartodb.createVis('map', 'viz.json', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: false,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 0,
        center_lon: 0,
        zoom: 10,
        time_slider: true,
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')
      slider.formatter(function(d) {
        return  d.getUTCMonth()+"-"+ d.getUTCDay() + " "+ d.getUTCHours() + ":"+ d.getUTCMinutes();
      })
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 3.12 this has been changed, try with the following code instead:

```
vis.timeSlider.formatter(function(d)
    return  d.getUTCMonth()+"-"+ d.getUTCDay() + " "+ d.getUTCHours() + ":"+ d.getUTCMinutes();
})
```

Comment: To show the day in format dd is better to use, getUTCDate(), getUTDay() gives instead the day of the week.